# Munkres: Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $x_1,x_2,... \in \prod X_{\alpha}$ (product space).

Suppose further that $x_1,x_2,..\to x$. Show $\pi_{\alpha}(x_1),\pi_{\alpha}(x_2),.., \to \pi_{\alpha}(x)$, for each $\alpha$.

Comment: I know that for every $U_{x_i}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x_{n} \in U \subset X_{\alpha}$ for $n \geq N$

Comment: the projections are continuous

Comment: Ok so just apply the projection and your done

Comment: @Rod: copper.hat seems to have answered your question. You may want to consider accepting his answer, or leaving a comment explaining what you are yet to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an index $\alpha'$, and let $U_{\alpha'} \subset X_{\alpha'}$ be an open set containing $\pi_{\alpha'}(x)$.

Let $U$ be the open set $\prod_\alpha U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha = X_\alpha $ for all $\alpha \neq \alpha'$, and note that $x \in U$. Then there exists some $N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \ge N$. If $x_n \in U$, then $(x_n)_{\alpha'} \in U_{\alpha'}$, and so $\pi_{\alpha'}(x_n) \in U_{\alpha'}$.